# Tag link suggestion plugin for WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, links, backlinks, tags

Every time I write a post I make sure I add links to words that I have tags for.

For example:
"The economy of [Brazil](http://blog.antinovaordemmundial.com/tag/brasil) has improved in the last few years"

This ensures that when people re-post my content, a lot of back-links will be created to my tags. This is quite a lot of work to do manually for every post.

It would be cool if there was a plugin that would suggest tags to be applied when they match existing words in the text of the post.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

Here are [several plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=tag+links&sort=) that may accomplish what you are looking to do. Good luck!